# javascript add onclick to html string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got the following html `string`

```
<span class="text">North-West</span>
```

I need to add an `onClick` to this `string` in order to make it look like the following:

```
<span class="text" onClick="mySomeFunction()">North-West</span>
```

I tried to convert this string to jQuery element back and forth, or to use `attr()` or `setAttribute()` functions but it did not work. Any ideas how to do that would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: `onClick` works only with form elements

Comment: never ever do inline js or inline css - it's bad practice that leads to hard-to-maintain code

Comment: what expected outcome you want?

Comment: @MilanChheda that is not at all true

Comment: try `onclick` without C as captal letter

Comment: @MilanChheda That's not accurate. `onclick` can be used for pretty much any element.

Comment: Alright! I take my comments back.

Comment: My question is actually how to add an `onClick` handler to the element. Of course I can make a seperate function for this, but I got only a string which I need to edit, so the question is basically about string editing

Comment: What did you actually try that is not working?

Comment: I would suggest doing some research into the [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) object and its methods then.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jQuery, maybe you could put the event in your script file?

```
$('.text').on('click', mySomeFunction);
```

This way, you have your code organised in a file and it's a better practice. Inline JS is not very clean.

Answer (score 0):

Without Jquery, using pure javascript:

Select your element

```
var t = document.querySelector('span');
```

Add your EventListener to detect the click

```
t.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log('test');
    someFunction();
})
```

```js
var t = document.querySelector('span');

t.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log('test');
    alert('function');
})
```

```html
<span class="text">North-West</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

html:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="myConfirmButton">
    Save changes
</button>
```

js:

```js
var okbutton = document.getElementById("myConfirmButton");

okbutton.setAttribute("onclick", "deletedata('msgid',165);");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).